# Header broke chain ancestry, Synchronisation failed, dropping peer & retrieved hash chain is invalid

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, light-clients, poa, clique

#### System information

**Geth version**:

```
Geth
Version: 1.8.22-stable
Git Commit: 7fa3509e2eaf1a4ebc12344590e5699406690f15
Architecture: arm
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11.5
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/home/pi/go
GOROOT=/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.11.5.linux.amd64
```

**OS & version**:

```
Linux raspberrypi-1 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**go-ethereum commit hash**:

N/A

**Engine**:

Clique

**Is private blockchain?**:

Yes

#### Expected behaviour

Able to sync latest blocks using Geth light client.

#### Actual behaviour

I got stucked at `Header broke chain ancestry`, `Synchronisation failed, dropping peer` and `retrieved hash chain is invalid` error.

At first, it managed to download all blocks until around 400,000-ish block. After that, I started to see the errors above.

I tried to replicate it (running Geth 1.8.22-stable light client) on OSX and Ubuntu machine (not Raspberry Pi) and I got the same errors. Restarting Geth and the machines did not solve the problem.

The full node that I'm connected to is running and sealing blocks every 15 seconds just fine. I did open the 30304 port too in the host firewall settings.

[image]

This is how I started the sealer node:

```
geth \
    --syncmode="full" \
    --datadir="/home/ubuntu/stand_alone_node" \
    --port="30304" \
    --networkid="88" \
    --ipcpath="/home/ubuntu/stand_alone_node/geth.ipc" \
    --rpc \
    --rpcport="8545" \
    --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" \
    --rpccorsdomain="*" \
    --rpcvhosts="*" \
    --ws \
    --wsport="8546" \
    --wsaddr="0.0.0.0" \
    --wsorigins="*" \
    --mine \
    --minerthreads="1" \
    --lightserv="50" \
    --lightpeers="100" \
    --unlock="0x..." \
    --password /home/ubuntu/stand_alone_node/sealer-password
```

#### Steps to reproduce & backtrace

```
$ cd /home/zulh/my-poa/

$ geth \
  --datadir . \
  --syncmode light \
  init genesis.json # <-- I'm using the same genesis file in full node and light node

$ geth \
  --syncmode light \
  --datadir . \
  --port 30305 \
  --networkid 88 \
  --ipcpath geth.ipc \
  --rpc \
  --rpcport 8547 \
  --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 \
  --rpccorsdomain "*" \
  --ws \
  --wsport 8548 \
  --wsaddr 0.0.0.0

WARN [02-14|02:50:57.907] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=1024 updated=309
INFO [02-14|02:50:57.914] Maximum peer count                       ETH=0 LES=100 total=25
WARN [02-14|02:50:57.919] Found deprecated node list file /home/zulh/my-poa/geth/static-nodes.json, please use the TOML config file instead.
INFO [02-14|02:50:57.922] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.22-stable-7fa3509e/linux-arm/go1.11.5
INFO [02-14|02:50:57.922] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/zulh/my-poa/geth/lightchaindata cache=154 handles=524288
INFO [02-14|02:50:57.989] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 88 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: <nil>  ConstantinopleFix: <nil> Engine: clique}"
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.023] Loaded most recent local header          number=452224 hash=3034bb…376388 td=880743 age=1w1d18h
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.094] UDP listener up                          net=enode://da006fa220e61658f9a2def4ec91ee186d5b57ecd9b6c1538a1f3c1050a4929aca922dca5e1420e419779c94690728a6d3defba8c68b7cca75aaf72594d255b6@[::]:30305
WARN [02-14|02:50:58.101] Light client mode is an experimental feature
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.108] New local node record                    seq=5 id=784bb25a42074d09 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30305 tcp=30305
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.108] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://da006fa220e61658f9a2def4ec91ee186d5b57ecd9b6c1538a1f3c1050a4929aca922dca5e1420e419779c94690728a6d3defba8c68b7cca75aaf72594d255b6@127.0.0.1:30305
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.109] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/zulh/my-poa/geth.ipc
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.110] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://0.0.0.0:8547                              cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.112] WebSocket endpoint opened                url=ws://[::]:8548
INFO [02-14|02:50:58.162] Block synchronisation started
WARN [02-14|02:51:15.195] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454379 hash=ad7ae1…521c51
WARN [02-14|02:51:23.185] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:51:28.478] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454380 hash=7b77bb…e8d388
WARN [02-14|02:51:36.810] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:51:58.505] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454382 hash=ba865d…40dc80
WARN [02-14|02:52:09.145] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:52:28.547] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454384 hash=685cbc…a9f316
WARN [02-14|02:52:36.853] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:52:58.652] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454386 hash=eb8903…ac72db
WARN [02-14|02:53:09.046] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:53:28.708] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454388 hash=498f79…b5e439
WARN [02-14|02:53:36.857] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:53:58.701] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454390 hash=3451c3…04cd19
WARN [02-14|02:54:09.161] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:54:28.797] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454392 hash=fbf7fd…c595a5
WARN [02-14|02:54:36.919] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:54:58.856] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454394 hash=d1d619…fbbc2f
WARN [02-14|02:55:09.288] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:55:28.916] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454396 hash=7319e8…24ec39
WARN [02-14|02:55:37.015] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:55:58.982] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454398 hash=7903a0…909107
WARN [02-14|02:56:09.163] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:56:29.024] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454400 hash=426edd…73c98b
WARN [02-14|02:56:37.193] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:56:59.082] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454402 hash=47ce07…b11a7f
WARN [02-14|02:57:09.449] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:57:29.136] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454404 hash=b3e8ee…24ec7d
WARN [02-14|02:57:37.191] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:57:59.194] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454406 hash=7fe68d…2ac88f
WARN [02-14|02:58:09.520] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:58:29.245] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454408 hash=08c7c1…fa0e1c
WARN [02-14|02:58:37.239] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:58:59.315] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454410 hash=238f3d…3fbbd1
WARN [02-14|02:59:09.635] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [02-14|02:59:29.369] Header broke chain ancestry              peer=2f2620dad919816a number=454412 hash=d1ff45…17dad5
WARN [02-14|02:59:37.154] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=2f2620dad919816a err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? I've been stucked with this problem for many days and I'm in serious need of help here.

I do really appreciate your help and inputs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm getting same issue but only when `syncmode` is `light`